# How to call function after 4pm and 12 am

Tags: jquery

I want to call my function when time is 4pm and 12am

How can i call that function using jquery?

I found one method setTimeout but its after some seconds i want to call that function when time is 4pm and 12am

Comment: You could use setTimeout to check the time every minute and then execute your function if it's 12AM. Anyway, the website has to be opened by a user to make this work... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: There is one div in my site i want to hide that div when time is 4pm and show it when time is 12am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SetInterval function to check what is the currenttime and based on that you can call your function.You can find more info on setInterval in the below link

http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var d = new Date();
        if (d.getHours() == 00) {
          $("#divid").show();
        }
         if (d.getHours() == 16) {
          $("#divid").hide();
        }

    }, 5000);
  });

 </script>
```